# How to include FragmentActivity layout in Activity layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I want to include a **FragmentActivity** layout in another AppCompatActivity layout.

In particular I want to show a Google map (in this case the **FragmentActivity**) inside a container of the other AppCompatActivity .
 i am going to show my code.

**1. The AppCompatActivity layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/map_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**2.The AppCompatActivity class**

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar _toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.map_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
    }
}
```

**3.The FragmentActivity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**4.The FragmentActivity class:**

```
public class MapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
}
```

When I run this just show the app bar on top and blank frame in the place that I needed to have the map.

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see your map layout inside your `MapActivity`. Furthermore you are using your map in a `FragmentActivity` not a `Fragment`. This is how I would do it.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private Toolbar _toolbar;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.map_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);

        initMap();
    }

    public void initMap() {
        MapFragment map = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {
            if (googleMap != null) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;                             
                mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);               
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR", "GOOGLE MAPS NOT LOADED");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would do this in my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/map_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you don't even need the MapFragmentActivity as its a bit redundant. Also you are now waiting for the map to be ready before you display it with the `implements OnMapReadyCallback`. This will save you some headaches later with inflating the fragment before its ready.

Comment: Yes but what about onCreate in the FragmentActivity class?

Comment: You don't need the FragmentActivity class, its redundant and this way you can control everything directly from your MapActivity so you don't run into problems with Context. MapFragment is something thats provided for you that is used for this exact purpose. To display the Google map

Comment: Ok I had the same thought from the begging to implement solution like this, without FragmentActivity. But I thought as hack. I prefer clear solution from the documantion

Comment: All this happens because I want to include the toolbar (app bar) that needs AppCompatActivity.

Comment: No, this is absolutely not a hack. This is exactly how the Google map was intended to be used. Try it out, trust me. I've worked a lot with the Google Map API's.

Answer (score 1):

Place the `MapFragment` into the `Layout` of `AppCompatActivity` instead.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/map_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
               <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This still gives me a blank fragment. Where is the reference in the fragment view to render the FragmenActivity layout?

Comment: Wait a sec... Have you followed the initial setup of Setting up `Map`?

Comment: yes.. the map that I already have is the default of the android studio.

Comment: I meant the `API Key` and all that.

Comment: Yes you are right... but yes I did already this. I can see the map when I start directly the map.

Comment: Okay... Take a screen shot of your screen. I'll see what how can i help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96911/discussion-between-trivial-and-thanassis).